# HTML horizontal scroll bar

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I am trying to add a horizontal scroll bar to a section (`<div>`) of an HTML page, but for some reason it is not working. The section of the page contains a number of small images that run horizontally across the page, but I don’t want to have to use the scroll bar at the bottom of the page to scroll through all the images. I just want the `<div>` section to have the scroll bar.

The section of HTML is shown below alongside the CSS that I tried:

```css
.photos .container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 700px;
  background-color: #00FF00;
  left: 10px;
  width: 1500px;
  height: 220px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
.photos .container .row .img1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.photos .container .row .img2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 190px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.photos .container .row .img3 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 326px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.photos .container .row .img4 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 469px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.photos .container .row .img5 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 779px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.photos .container .row .img6 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 922px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.photos .container .row .img7 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1058px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.photos .container .row .img8 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1185px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.photos .container .row .img9 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1485px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.photos .container .row .img10 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1628px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.photos .container .row .img11 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1774px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="photos">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="img1">
        <img src="images\photos\small\image_00001.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="img2">
        <img src="images\photos\small\image_00002.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="img3">
        <img src="images\photos\small\image_00003.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="img4">
        <img src="images\photos\small\image_00004.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="img5">
        <img src="images\photos\small\image_00005.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="img6">
        <img src="images\photos\small\image_00006.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="img7">
        <img src="images\photos\small\image_00007.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="img8">
        <img src="images\photos\small\image_00008.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="img9">
        <img src="images\photos\small\image_00009.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="img10">
        <img src="images\photos\small\image_00010.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="img11">
        <img src="images\photos\small\image_00011.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What about `aside` inside your `section`?

Comment: @SerCrAsh was that comment meant for this question?

Comment: @DanielBeck If he need a left/right side element like an scrollbar he could make a aside element inside the section element.

Comment: @ED209 Your existing CSS works perfectly if you set .photos .container to width:100% instead of a fixed width that may not match the window size.  (It's overcomplicated, I don't see the need to absolute-position every element in it, but it does work.)

Answer (score 0):

Oh I figured it out. I just changed:-

```
.photos .container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 700px; 
    background-color: #00FF00;
    left: 10px;
    width: 1500px;
    height: 220px;    
    overflow-x: scroll;
}

to 

.photos .container .row {
    position: absolute;
    top: 700px; 
    background-color: #00FF00;
    left: 10px;
    width: 1500px;
    height: 220px;    
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```